# Performant canvas in .net

Tags: c#, .net, canvas

I am quite amazed at what you can now do in an html5 canvas/svg driven by javascript, and I would like to know if there is any drawing library for .NET that would have similar performance and simplicity of use. I am thinking that if there were, then I could build some kind of tool that would be like d3.js for .net.

I am looking for a library that would allow me to draw svg-like elements in real time.

Any idea?

Comment: There are drawing APIs for .NET - the `System.Drawing` namespace is one. There is also a [managed directx api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164112.aspx). And there are third party vector graphics APIs. And of course, there is WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using WPF and the canvas control](http://wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html) you can do SVG like "drawing" very easy and like the HTML5 canvas is ofter hardware accelerated.

Other options would be using the DirectX api, either wrapped or native, XNA for pure game development or the GDI(+) library.

Comment: The wpf canvas tool is great for this. Couple it with the easy geometric drawing tools and you'll have everything you need to duplicate javascript driven drawing.